# Urllib request takes too long to respond

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urlopen

Below is my code. The last line takes too long to respond. It has been more 30 minutes but no respond yet. I appreciate if anyone has any idea.

```
import urllib.request 
html = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.sahibinden.com').read()
```

Comment: The remote server may hold your connection for any number of reasons set a socket timeout for urllib.

Comment: Thank you @awiebe !Your suggestion solved my problem.